# Migrating codebase from p4 to git - looking for a step by step guide

Tags: git, migration, perforce, git-p4

I'm trying to migrate a perforce repository to git. I'm following this [link](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4) and also I have gone through numerous stackoverflow questions. Finally now I'm able to migrate p4 code to git. However, I want to achieve 1 more thing post the migration.

Migration steps that I followed:

```
git p4 clone //depot/development/<path>/main/@all

git remote add origin git@github.com:<org>/demo.git

git branch -M main

git push -u origin main
```

Above steps work fine for 1 time migration.

Lets say there is a new commit in the perforce and I want to sync it to the git? How do I do it?

Steps I tried.

```
1. git p4 sync (works)

2. git rebase

3. git push -u origin main
```

No errors. However, I don't see the new p4 commit on the git. I'm sure I'm missing something here. Can anyone point me in the correct direction? I want to preserve the timestamp, author and ofcourse the changes in the commit when its sync'd to git. Also, I'm quite new to Git. A 1 liner on any command on what it does(if there are any command that I need to execute) really would help me understand it better. If you need any more details I'm happy to provide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't tried to re-produce this, but maybe the sync has put the changes on the original p4 branch, not your renamed branch?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it with a test server.

If you do `git log remotes/p4/master` you'll probably see the new commits, but git-p4 sync doesn't put them into a local branch.

If instead of:

```
git p4 sync
git rebase
```

You do:

```
git p4 rebase
```

You should get the new commits on your local branch.

You might want to do the original clone with `--branch=main` so that the perforce branch name is `//remotes/p4/main` rather than `//remotes/p4/master`